# getting/setting unique id to a leafletjs circlemarker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map with several markers on it. I construct these markers with this piece of code:

```
var markers = {},
    lbl = 'unique';

markers[lbl] = L.circleMarker(ll, 
      { radius: 8,  
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        color: '#00ff00',
        weight: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.9,
        className: 'svgMarker'
       })
  .bindLabel('This is '+lbl)
  .addTo(markerLayer)
  .addTo(map)
  .on('click', clickHandler);;
```

Within the clickHandler I want to load some stuff depending on *which* marker I clicked. To distinguish them, I have a `lbl` (label)var which holds the unique alphanumeric ID of the marker.

```
function clickHandler(event){
   //- zoom to the marker
   map.setView(ev.latlng, 16);

   //- Load the marker dependent stuff.
   // how can I pass the unique label to this function?

}
```

Is there a way to pass the unique id with the mouse event or is there an other way to give a 'property' to the marker which I can read out in the clickHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a property to your marker (just javascript stuff) ... you can get it back with context 'this' in the event handler

```
var marker = L.marker([48.8588589,2.3470599]);
marker.id = 'unique_id';
marker.addTo(map);

marker.on('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
     console.log(this.id);
}
```